# jQuery make addClass clickable

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I have an li which, using jQuery when clicked adds the class "active":

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I then want the class to be removed once it is clicked again:

```
 $('.active').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

However nothing happens on click, I imagine this is because the class didnt exist in the first place, I am using $(document).ready();

Is there any way of accessing an added variable, or am I missing something really obvious which is causing nothing to happen when clicking on the added class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the `.active` class is amended at runtime, therefore you cannot bind any event handlers to it on load of the page. To solve this you could use a delegated event handler instead:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', (function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Note that this will replace both the event handlers in the code of your question.

Comment: technically, event delegation isn't needed. but probably isn't a bad idea anyway.

Comment: True, perhaps the 'need' is overstated, but I'd argue this is by far the neater solution to binding/rebinding event handlers. I'll amend the wording